PHP: include a script file from a root directory subdirectory (_private) in a subdomain
I spent hours researching, reading, and trial/error-ing to no avail.
I have a family website (http://www.TheMichelPage.com) that has a lot of subdomains. I thought the domains are supposed to be set up as subdirectories off the root. I have a PHP script file in a root/_private directory that I want to access from, say, http://roadtrips.TheMichelPage.com (which should be \dir\dir\dir\michelpage\roadtrips).
For javascripts, I was able to use the include to the root/_private directory (I think that was on this forum somewhere - worked great).
However, the PHP isn't working quite the same way. When I INCLUDE or INCLUDE_ONCE, the page doesn't see the root/_private/scripts.php file.
I left the test output at the top of the page in question. I know I could have an /_private directory in each of the domains (18 or so of them) but then I'd have to copy the script to all those directories if I change anything.  (I also don't understand why the DOCUMENT_ROOT includes the "/kunden" but the DIR does not.)
While not included in the below, I did also try INCLUDE "../_private/scripts.php".
Hopefully I explained everything sufficiently. Any thoughts how to resolve this?
Thanks.
Here is the output I have showing the code itself and the result:
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = /htdocs/michelpage/roadtrips
__DIR__ = /homepages/htdocs/michelpage/roadtrips
dirname(__DIR__, 1)./_private/scripts.php = /homepages/htdocs/michelpage/_private/scripts.php
$File = /homepages/htdocs/michelpage/_private/scripts.php
File $File NOT found

One iteration of the INCLUDE line of code that isn't working (I put various iterations of the above into the INCLUDE file name is (the DIR below does NOT have a space before or after the double-underscores, I had to add it to remove the formatting):
include_once(dirname(__ DIR __, 1)."_private/scripts.php");

The error message suggests that you put the $File in quotes, so it was taken literally rather than being replaced with its value. Please post your code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I added a sample INCLUDE statement that doesn't... include.  But the larger block of code with output has the actual lines of code.

After another two hours of effort, I determined the answer.

The in-line if test for the INCLUDE (with and without apostrophes surrounding the $File) was throwing inaccurate answers:
echo "File $File ". ( ( (include $File) == "TRUE") ? "" : "NOT") . " included"


while FILE_EXISTS was working as expected (which helped me get to 2 below).
2) I built the directory structure and combined the path of the scripts file into the INCLUDE statement, and that seemed to work.
include_once( dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], 1)."/_private/scripts.php" )

